# MongoDb: Difference between $push/$addtoset

Tags: mongodb

I read the documentation in the MongoDb and I used a simple proves and I only look that:
Push is sorting the array but `addtoSet` isn't it.

For me visually is the same, I don't know the difference.

Could anybody explain me the difference?

Another think if it could be in spanish or in a simple english, i'll aprecite it.

Comment: `$push` never sort an array. Both `$push` and `$addToSet` add new elements to the end on a target array.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

`$addToSet` do not add the item to the given field if it already contains it, on the other hand `$push` will add the given object to field whether it exists or not.

```
{_id: "docId", items: [1, 2]}
db.items.update({_id:"docId"}, {$addToSet:{items: 2}}); // This won't update the document as it already contains 2
db.items.update({_id:"docId"}, {$push: {items:2}}); // this will update the document. new document {_id: "docId", items:[1,2,2]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation now i'm doing another example and i'm knowing better this time.

Comment: Also, `$addToSet` does not affect existing duplicate elements.

Answer (score 35):

**$push** - adds items in the order in which they were received. Also you can add same items several times.

**$addToSet** - adds just unique items, but order of items is not guaranteed.

If you need to add unique items in order, you can group and add elements via $addToSet, then $unwind the array with elements, $sort by items, and then do $group again with $push items.

Answer (score 3):

Along side the differences that others have mentioned

- `$push`: Appends an object to an array
- `$addToSet`: Adds an object to an array if it does not exists

There is a difference in replication.  (This can be seen if by taking a look at `local.oplog.rs`)

- `$push` operations (that actually modified the array) are replicated as `$set.items.INDEX: item`
- `$addToSet` operations (that actually modified the array) are replicated as `$set.items: [THE_ENTIRE_ARRAY]`

If you are dealing with large arrays, then the difference might be significant

So while something like (the typical use case to maintain unique array)

```
db.items.updateOne(
  {_id: 'my-id', 'items': {'$ne': 'items1'},
  {'$push': {
    'items': 'item1',
  }}
)

db.items.updateOne(
  {_id: 'my-id'},
  {'$addToSet': {
    'items': 'item1',
  }}
)
```

might end up with the same resulting document, there is a difference in the replicated operation.

Answer (score 2):

$addToSet and $push does the same thing, however $push just pushes any item disregarding the duplication causing redundancy. The former pushes only unique items, no duplication.

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggest $addToSet (set) wont allow duplicates
while $push simply add the element to array

Answer (score 0):

$push: Inserts the value to an array in the resulting document. 
eg;

```
db.mycol.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$by_user", url : {$push: "$url"}}}])
```

$addToSet: Inserts the value to an array in the resulting document but does not create duplicates.
eg;

```
db.mycol.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$by_user", url : {$addToSet : "$url"}}}])
```