# Can we push object value into $project using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db.setting.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      status: true,
      deleted_at: 0,
      _id: {
        $in: [
          ObjectId("5c4ee7eea4affa32face874b"),
          ObjectId("5ebf891245aa27c290672325")
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "site",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "admin_id",
      as: "data"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      status: 1,
      price: 1,
      currency: 1,
      numberOfRecord: {
        $size: "$data"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      numberOfRecord: 1
    }
  }
])
```

how to push the currency into price object using project please guide thanks a lot, also eager to know what is difference between $addtoSet and $push, what is good option to opt it from project or fix it from $addField

https://mongoplayground.net/p/RiWnnRtksb4

Output should be like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ebf891245aa27c290672325"),
    "currency": "USD",
    "name": "Menz",
    "numberOfRecord": 0,
    "price": {
      "numberDecimal": "20",
      "currency": "USD",
    },
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5c4ee7eea4affa32face874b"),
    "currency": "USD",
    "name": "Dave",
    "numberOfRecord": 2,
    "price": {
      "numberDecimal": "10",
     "currency": "USD"
    },
    "status": true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the object structure while projecting, so in this case there's no need for either `$push` or `$addToSet`.

```
{
    $project: {
      name: "1",
      status: 1,
      price: {
        currency: "$currency",
        numberDecimal: "$price.numberDecimal"
      },
      currency: 1,
      numberOfRecord: {
        $size: "$data",

      }
    }
  }
```

Now the difference between `$push` and `$addToSet` is pretty trivial and derived from the name, `$push` saves all items while `$addToSet` will just create a set of them, for example:

input:

```
[
    //doc1
    {
        item: 1
    },
    //doc2
    {
        item: 2
    },
    //doc3
    {
        item: 1
    }
]
```

Now this:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        items: {$push: "$item"}
    }
}
```

Will result in: 
`{_id: null, items: [1, 2, 1]}`

While:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        items: {$addToSet: "$item"}
    }
}
```

Will result in: 
`{_id: null, items: [1, 2]}`

Comment: Hey Tom thanks for explanation so no duplicate value if we use $addToSet

Comment: is it possible if we have $numberDecimal into price object get data like : https://mongoplayground.net/p/xDvOx0LL52G

Comment: In this case just use `price` instead of `price.numberDecimal` in the `$project`

Answer (score 3):

You can insert a field into an object with `project` directly, like this (field `price`):

```
$project: {
      name: 1,
      status: 1,
      price: {
        numberDecimal: "$price.numberDecimal",
        currency: "$currency"
      },
      numberOfRecord: {
        $size: "$data"
      }
    }
```

By doing it with project, there is no need to use `$addField`.

For the difference between `$addToSet` and `$push`, read this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248556/mongodb-difference-between-push-addtoset).

Comment: Thanks for this https://mongoplayground.net/p/vwELMGuX4CR see this i have "$numberDecimal" amount in that case price: {
        numberDecimal: "$price.$numberDecimal",
        currency: "$currency"
      },
FieldPath field names may not start with '$' getting errror

Comment: Yes, you have to remove the $ before numberDecimal, so it is : `"$price.numberDecimal"`. Also, remove the $ before numberDecimal in the database. See: https://mongoplayground.net/p/kCpPLxXRBcd

Comment: Yes agree don't know why database adding $ while creating any idea if you have 
I Know The dollar ($) prefixed field '$numberDecimal' in 'price.$numberDecimal' is not valid for storage.

Comment: Or is this possible to use project using '$numberDecimal'